# Custom dialog in android asynctask

Tags: android

Whats the wrong in onPostExecute. Its showing the error in that method. Working fine for ProgressDialog. json and database handlers are all working properly. Same thinf has been done for ProgressDialog.

```
class ProcessBalance  extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<String>> {

        private Dialog dialog;

        /**
         * Before starting background thread
         * Show Progress Bar Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

             final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(UserhomeActivity.this);
             dialog.setTitle("test");
             dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialoglayout);
             dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.DialogAnimation;
             Button btnDismiss = (Button)dialog.getWindow().findViewById(R.id.dismiss);
           //  TextView balview = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        //     balview.setText("Please wait for the balance.");

             //http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/

             btnDismiss.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

               public void onClick(View v) {
                   dialog.dismiss();
               }});

             dialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Downloading file in background thread
         * */
        @Override
        protected List<String> doInBackground(String... args0) {
        //  DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
            //HashMap<String, String> user = db.getUserDetails();
            UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
            //JSONObject json = userFunction.getBalance(user.get("mobile_no"));
            JSONObject json = userFunction.getBalance("1234567890");
            List<String> LIST = new ArrayList<String>();
            try {
                if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                    String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);
                    LIST.add(json.getString("success"));
                    LIST.add(json.getString("balance"));
            }

            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
            catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return LIST;
        }


        /**
         * After completing background task
         * Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/

        protected void onPostExecute(List<String> result) {

            String responseCodestr = result.get(0);
            final int responseCode = Integer.parseInt(responseCodestr);
            String bal = result.get(1);
            TextView balview = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

            if(responseCode==1){
                 balview.setText("test "+bal);
            } else {
                  balview.setText("test2");
            }

        }

      }
```

Comment: what is the error? provide stack trace if needed.

Comment: what happens when you get the `TextView balview = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textView1);` in `onPreExecute` and then try to set the text in `onPostExecute`?

Comment: Change `(Button)dialog.getWindow().findViewById(R.id.dismiss);` with `(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.dismiss);`

Answer (score 1):

You have two dialogs, one as a member an another final one defined in onPreExecute. You should change the below code

```
    private Dialog dialog;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

         final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(UserhomeActivity.this);
```

for this:

```
    private final Dialog dialog;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

         this.dialog = new Dialog(UserhomeActivity.this);
```

Comment: Good one! Thanks all specially AitorTheRed :) its working as you have said.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you have declared dialog twice.

One is before onPreExcecute

```
 private Dialog dialog;
```

One is inside onPreExcecute

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(UserhomeActivity.this);
```

The dialog you are initializing is second one and the dialog you are trying to use in onPostExceute is first one.

Solution is

change

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(UserhomeActivity.this);
```

to

```
dialog = new Dialog(UserhomeActivity.this);
```